# Error While using SQLCMD in PDW

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, parallel-data-warehouse

I'm using SQLCMD in PDW for extracting data into a flat file. The command line syntax is given below:

```
sqlcmd -S "10.20.30.40,19001" -d MyPDW_DB -U PDW_User -P Password1 -Q "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; SELECT * FROM MyPDW_DB.dbo.SampleFact" -o "FactOut.txt" -s"|"
```

When I try to execute the batch file, I get the following error:

**Msg 104409, Level 16, State 1, Server PdwTdsServer, Line 1
Setting QuotedIdentifier to 'OFF' is not supported.**

I am assuming this is due to the fact that there is a "comma" in the server name (IP address,Port Number). I can use this command for extracting data from SQL tables. Any idea on how I can make this working for PDW?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing  "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; " from your query since your  not using any Keywords as tablename.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that as well. But I get the same error.

Comment: What error you're getting now? I believe it is not the same as above since you removed set QuotedIdentifier to 'OFF' .

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error: 
**Msg 104409, Level 16, State 1, Server PdwTdsServer, Line 1
Setting QuotedIdentifier to 'OFF' is not supported.**

That's reason I suspect it has something to do with the "comma" in the server name, though the error message is not very helpful.

Comment: try running this one:   
sqlcmd -S 10.20.30.40 -d MyPDW_DB -U PDW_User -P Password1 -Q "SELECT * FROM MyPDW_DB.dbo.SampleFact" -o "FactOut.txt"

Comment: I cannot connect to the PDW instance without the port number. However, I tried what you suggested but it didn't work either. :-|

Comment: Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478957/unable-to-access-an-instance-of-sql-server-2008-r2-remotely

Answer (score 4):

I got this working partially.

```
sqlcmd -S "10.20.30.40,19001" -d MyPDW_DB -U PDW_User -P Password1 -I -Q "SELECT * FROM MyPDW_DB.dbo.SampleFact" -o "FactOut.txt" -s"|"
```

For setting the quoted_identifier OFF, the option to use is "-I". However, I'm still trying to find an alternative for "SET NOCOUNT ON" option which is not supported in PDW. If someone can help me with that, I'd greatly appreciate that.